# Warn certain users about host down, but not service states

Tags: nagios

My boss is starting to complain that he gets too many emails from my icinga/nagios instance and so am i to be honest, and he doesn't need to know everything, neither does development.

So what i want to do, is to limit the amount of email is sent out.

I started by removing contact_groups from hosts, and instead apply these to individual services that they care about, all well and good.

But, for certain hosts i would like notifications be sent out on a host down, but not services defined. How would i go on about doing that?

TLDR: how to make nagios email user about host down, but not services on that host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these users who don't need all of the details, look at service_notifications_enabled as the contact config option. This will only give them host notifications. You can do ALL kinds of things to fine tune your notifications with Nagios, so don't waste them if people don't need to get them, otherwise they'll just get filtered into a mailbox that no one ever reads.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#contact

Comment: Thanks that looks like a great place to start

Comment: Do you know how to override service_notifications_enabled if i want a user to get only host alerts but also alerts for a spesific servic eon the host but no others?

Comment: For this you need to start setting notifications at the service level, not the host level. If you add a contact for a service, and not a host, they'll only get notifications for that service. If you add a contact to a host, they will get all service notifications.

Comment: Yeah, so i can't get notification on host states + selected services (not all of them)? That seems weird, i'm thinking there is something i am missing

I am aware i can disable notifications on a service, but i would like some groups to get them, just not others

Comment: The quick and easy way is just to have a check_ping as a service, which is the same as the host check. I'm a little rusty on my notification tricks though, so if you need to dive deeper, head to support.nagios.com/forum. They've got a Nagios Core forum there.